# What does it mean to have an already registered worktree?

Tags: git, sandbox

I'm developing inside a sandbox (linux sandboxer) enviroment. When doing git push, the test system throws this error:

```
git.exc.GitCommandError: Cmd('git') failed due to: exit code(128)
  cmdline: git worktree add /var/lib/snapshooter/instances/xxxxxxxxxxxxx
  stdout: 'Preparing worktree (detached HEAD xxxxxx)'
  stderr: 'fatal: '/var/lib/snapshooter/instances/xxxxxxxxxxxxx' is a missing but already registered worktree;
use 'add -f' to override, or 'prune' or 'remove' to clear'
```

I already ran git prune ,git gc, and regenerated the SSH key but I do not know what else to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [git worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree).

The test system creates an extra worktree to do something with the commits you are pushing. It encountered an error. The worktree `/var/lib/snapshooter/instances/xxxxxxxxxxxxx` had been created during a previous push. But it was not pruned properly. To fix the error, ask the test system administrator to run `git worktree prune` in the main worktree. The main worktree is on the test system machine.